# The number of different symmetric matrices of order $5$ with each element being either $0$ or $1$

Tags: linear-algebra

The number of different symmetric matrices of order $5$ with each element being either $0$ or $1$

A. $5!$

B. $5^5$

C. $2^{15}$

D. $5^{15}$

Comment: What is meant by "order 5"?  Are you asking for 5x5 matrices, as Robert Lewis wrote as an answer, or are you referring to all matrices of any size which, when taken to its fifth power, produces the identity?

Comment: I meant to say a 5x5 symmetric matrix that is square symmetric matrix of order 5.

Answer (score 1):

Since we restrict ourselves to symmetric matrices, we only need concern ourselves with upper triangular matrices, for we can reflect the entries across the main diagonal to fill the matrix out.  In a $5 \times 5$ upper triangular matrix, the number of available "slots" is

$5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15; \tag 1$

since each slot may be independently occupied by $0$ or $1$, there are $2^{15}$ such matrices.